# Graph theory - The clients can still communicate with all the remaining servers

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, computer-science

I have the following graph problem that I have no idea how to solve. Could you help me please? I need a proof.

In a computer network there are two types of nodes: client and server. Each client is directly
connected (using network cables) to at least one server and there are no direct connections between
clients. Suppose that each server can route messages to other servers with which it is directly connected
and the entire network is connected. In order to make the network more reliable, a scenario is considered:

Every client is directly connected to at least 2 servers and every pair of servers having the
distance between them 2 are connected using a direct cable.

Prove that, in this new network, if
a server becomes unavailable the clients can still communicate with all the remaining servers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the server the became unavaible.

If a client was not connected to $S$, it's still connected to at least $2$ other servers, and each of those is connected to all other servers.

If a client was connected to $S$, it's still connected to at least one other server, and each of those is connected to all other servers.

Regardless of the situation, the client can communicate to all other servers.